# Excel gives FALSE value instead of number result

Tags: excel

My excel is giving me a FALSE instead of the result.

Here is the formula I've used:

```
=IF(D4>=15,IF(AND(E4>=5,F4>=5,I4>=5),(E4*0.25+F4*0.25+I4*0.3+K4*0.2),(G4*0.5+I4*0.3+K4*0.2)))
```

[image]

Comment: The first IF doesn’t have a false clause and it’s false because you’re comparing an integer 15 to a percentage

Comment: For simplicity and ease of understanding try not to embed functions into other functions. You could for example calculate `E4*0.25+F4*0.25+I4*0.3+K4*0.2`in one cell, `G4*0.5+I4*0.3+K4*0.2` in another cell and so on. Then chain functions together.